# Configure nginx to serve cached images

Tags: nginx

I have a Rails app which generates a lot of images; ie an images controller with a show action fetches an image from a SAN and serves it. I have a caches_page on this which reliably saves a copy of the file in a custom location; RAILS_ROOT + /public/cache. The files are there and look fine.

I am serving the app through nginx and it seems to work fine but for the life of me I can't get it to send those cached image files instead of hitting the rails action. I'm pretty new to nginx and have been researching it for some time but not matter what I try it doesn't work - I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

To clarify, I have a uri like this:

```
/images/show/123.jpg
```

the file may exist here:

```
/cache/images/show/123.jpg
```

How can I make nginx serve that file and not pass on the request?

Here's an incomplete list of what I've tried:

```
if (-f /cache$request_filename) { 
  rewrite (.*) /cache$1 break;
  break; 
}

if (-f /cache$uri.jpg) {
rewrite (.*) /cache$1.jpg break;
}

if (-f /cache/images/show/$request_filename) {
rewrite (.*) /cache/images/show/$1.jpg break;
}
```

Any ideas?

update: I answered my own question. The correct rule was:

```
      if (-f $document_root/cache$request_uri) {
      rewrite (.*) /cache$1 break;
      }
```

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/262995/how-do-i-dry-up-this-nginx-configuration/263854#263854
http://serverfault.com/questions/263223/nginx-serve-htm-if-exists-instead-of-php/263395#263395

Answer (score 3):

the recommended way for nginx is using 
[the "try_files" directive](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files)

something like

```
location /images/show {
    root ...;
    try_files $document_root/cache$uri /fromrootpath/$uri;
}
```

Comment: `try_files` is a good approach (better than if statements.) But I think that directive should be `try_files $document_root/cache$uri $uri;` so it falls back to the requested uir if the cached images is not found.

Comment: @myanimal sure, fixed

Answer (score 2):

You could also cache images directly on Nginx using [MemcachedModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpMemcachedModule).